# Why does setItem() not assign values to item? <h1>{item.name}</h1> is not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been unable to display the name of the item, as it seems to be undefined.Though I am assigning items to item state property using setItem(), still in console if I display item, it is a empty object.

```
    function ItemDetail(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem();
  }, []);

  const [item, setItem] = useState({});

  const fetchItem = async () => {
    const fetchedItem = await fetch(
      `https://fortniteapi.io/v1/items/get?id=${props.match.params.id}&lang=en`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "79eab64a-7ec8a675-4d410f47-4a7304f4",
        },
      }
    );
    const itemn = await fetchedItem.json();
    setItem(itemn);
    console.log(item);
  };
  console.log(item.name);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{item.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you console log ```itemn```?

Answer (score 0):

I think your fetch has not completed before the `console.log` and return calls are made, causing `item.name` to be `undefined`.

Your `console.log` will usually fire before your `setItem` has finished setting the state, because setting state is an asynchronous operation. Your `console.log` displays an empty object, because you initialise the state to an empty item. Therefore, your console logs an empty object, as the state has not been changed before the `console.log` is called.

Another thing is that this happens in your return function as well. Because the return is calculated on the first execution of the component, your item has not been fetched yet. It is trying to access `item.name`, but `item` is an empty object so you get `undefined`. You should check first if `item.name != undefined` and then return the div. You can do this with a ternary operator like:

```
{item.name 
? <div>
  <h1>{item.name}</h1>
 </div>
: <div><h1>Item has not loaded yet!</h1></div>}
```

Which checks `item.name` before returning the div. It gives false when item is undefined, because [undefined is considered falsy in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Alternatively, you could look at what the API actually gives as a response by console.logging `itemn`. You might have to set the state as `itemn.data` for example. But that's difficult to say without seeing `itemn` logged.

Comment: I have checked the API response, and there is no issue with that. So it may be the case that before `fetch()` is being completed, the `setItem()` and `return` is getting executed. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Also if I `console.log(itemn)` before `setItem(itemn)`, `itemn` displays the API response in the console, but `setItem(itemn)` not working.

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the output of both console.log(fetchedItem) and console.log(itemn)? I already told you how to solve the return execution before the fetch with the code I posted, as for the fetch, that looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68zxg.png)

[Console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OJRf.png)